# Is it alright to call len() in a loop's conditional statement?

Tags: python, arrays, list

In C, it is considered bad practice to call strlen like this:

```
for ( i = 0; strlen ( str ) != foo; i++ )
{
    // stuff
}
```

The reason, of course, is that it is inefficient since it "counts" the characters in a string multiple times.

However, in Python, I see code like this quite often:

```
for i in range ( 0, len ( list ) ):
    # stuff
```

Is this bad practice? Should I store the result of len() in a variable and use that?

Comment: I hope you don't see code like that, but for a completely different reason: Python provides direct iteration, and the code you're showing is going out of its way to make things harder than necessary. You can get the items of `my_list` directly with `for item in my_list:`; there is no need to generate indexes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Python, a `for` loop iterates through a list-like object, it doesn't have a conditional statement that is checked each time. To illustrate, the following two loops are functionally equivalent; the `while` loop is a direct translation of `for (i=0; i< n; i++) { ... }`, while the `for` loop is the Pythonic way of doing it:

```
i = 0
while i < n:
   # do some actions using i
   i += 1

for i in range(n):
   # do some actions using i
```

In the `for` loop, `range(n)` is evaluated before the loop starts, and *then* its return value is used in the loop. In other words, `range(n)` is evaluated once (and only once) to get the list* of values that `i` should take.

So in the specific example given, Python sees `for i in range(0, len(list))`, evaluates `range(0, len(list))` (so `len` is called once) and stores the output (it doesn't call `range` (or `len`) again).

(* in Python 3.x `range` doesn't actually return a list, but when using it in a for loop there is no difference in functionality)

Answer (score 6):

Writing `for i in range(len(whatever))` is poor style in Python. As others have mentioned, direct iteration is available via `for element in whatever`. However, people keep doing it anyway for two reasons:

1. They're C programmers and haven't wrapped their heads around direct iteration.
2. They want to modify the list while iterating through it, or otherwise need the indices. If this is the case, the Pythonic way to do it is the `enumerate` function: `for i, element in enumerate(whatever)`.

Comment: What if you wish to iterate two equal-sized lists and join together their elements in pairs (matched by index) for another data structure?

Comment: In that case, use `zip`.

Answer (score 3):

This is fine in python because the `range` function creates a list that the for loop subsequently uses. Therefore `len` is only called once. Also, you don't need the extra 0 there because `range` starts counting from 0 if no extra options are there.

As a side note, you'll usually want to use `xrange` instead since it creates a generator that is evaluated lazily.

Comment: Note: In python 3 range creates a generator and xrange has been removed.

Comment: @jamylak Of course, I just assumed earlier versions. The day that all python code is written for python 3 will be a great day.